# Creating a relational database containing zip codes that need to be matched to 3 diffrent suppliers

Tags: mysql, database, database-normalization

I am trying to make a price comparison module in php which pulls records from a database the comparison module makes a calculation based on user input.
One of these inputs are the first 3 digits of the zip code, the zip code then gets matched with the correct variables in order to make the calculation. The variables being: gasregion (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8) energysupplier: (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h) gassupplier:(a, b, c, d, e, f).

zipcodes can be matched in all possible combinations e.g.:
zipcode 334 could be gasregion 3, energysupplier b and gassuplier d
zipcode 335 could be gasregion 3, energysupplier c and gassuplier e

to make matters more confusing energysupplier a, b, c, d, e, f are the same as gassupplier: a, b, c, d, e, f only have diffrent tarrifs for gas and energy.

I know how to code the comparison module the diffculty for me is designing the database as i have little experince with relational databases.

Could anyone give me a nod in the right direction?

Comment: Please show the start of a straightforward design. (There isn't anything in your question yet to suggest doing anything more than that, and explaining that is too broad a question.) PS This doesn't have anything to do per se with normalization. Also you'll likely get more hits if you add some other tags like database-design.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (for the programmer) to do this is to build a 1000-row table, with each row containing columns like these.

```
 zip3  gasregion  energysupplier  gassuplier
  000    2             q             r
  001    3             a             b
  002    7             w             x
     ...
  999    1             a             z
```

Then you can join this table to a possible customer table.